# INNER JOIN on value instead of dimension

Tags: sql

This is a tricky and (in my humble opinion) unnecessary question my friend got during an interview process, which I also did not know when he asked me about it. When you run this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (Null), (Null), (Null)) AS tb1 (col)
  JOIN (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (Null), (Null)) AS tb2 (col)
    ON tb1.col = tb2.col
```

It generates this result:

| tb1.col | tb2.col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Why this JOIN works like that?

Comment: That's a join of 2x `1`s from the first table with 3x `1`s from the second table. Total of 6 (2x3) rows. What were you expecting?

Comment: And remember that null isn't equal to null.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks! Didn't know about the null inequality. That clarified a lot!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by jarlh, the NULLs are not compared when executing `tb1.col = tb2.col`.

As for what all the 1's are, perhaps the following query will help understanding where each value comes from.
In this example, we compare the first letter of the values (which is always the letter A)

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('Abigail'), ('Allie'), (Null), (Null), (Null)) AS tb1 (col)
JOIN (VALUES ('Aria'), ('Allison'), ('Audrey'), (Null), (Null)) AS tb2 (col)
ON left(tb1.col, 1) = left(tb2.col, 1)
```

| col | col |
| --- | --- |
| Abigail | Aria |
| Abigail | Allison |
| Abigail | Audrey |
| Allie | Aria |
| Allie | Allison |
| Allie | Audrey |